# Highcharts Image Renderer Auto Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I am trying to put up a logo on the top left corner of the graph and the below code is working fine, but what i wanted to know is is their any **direct** way by which i can make either height or width **auto** like we do in CSS?

```
function (chart) {          
    chart.renderer.image("http://i.imgur.com/mX5qRdP.png", 5,5, 30, 30).add();
}
```

I know i can do it by calculating height and width this way..

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';
```

But is their any more sophisticated way?

Answer (score 3):

Highcharts is an SVG librarie, and the SVG 1.1 specification requires the `width` and `height` attributes for the `<image>` element.

See the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElementWidthAttribute) to see the attributes definitions.

> What i wanted to know is their any direct way by which i can make either height or width auto like we do in CSS?

Actually, I don't think there is a way to have the automatic size like css because SVG needs a number for the attributes `width` and `height` of the `<image>` element.